# Is it possible to convert a 'List Workflow' to 'Reusable Workflow' in Share Point Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I wish to create a Re-usable workflow from List workflow using share point 2010.When i tried the some of the articles steps using import and export visio but final option 'radio-button' to select 'list' or 'reusable' workflow is not shown in final pop up.So it failed.

1.Then I tried it using share point designer 2013.It throws error."Microsoft server different from share Point Designer".Is it possible to open 2010 created server in share point designer 2013.

2.when i tried to edit the workflow it shows share point cannot display this item.I deleted the cache info's folders but it shows the same error.

3.Is it possible to convert a  'List Workflow' to 'Reusable Workflow' in Share Point Designer 2010?

How to resolve these issues.I'm new to share point.please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a shareoint designer 2013. I'm not sure but it can be a bug in SharePoint Designer 2010.

This link can help after installing 2013 Designer. 
https://expertsin.cloud/2017/05/31/sharepoint-designer-workflows-converting-list-workflows-to-reusable-workflows/

Comment: Hello @Ahmed, thanks for your contribution, Please do not only provide links as answers. If the link breaks the answer will be of very little help, it is better to add the important steps from your links then add the link as reference!